Fallo búsqueda por fechas en Js y Ajax
Estoy modificando el sistema de búsqueda de una app web de un compañero.
Mi objetivo es cambiar en un cuadro de búsqueda la forma en la que se aplica el filtro de fecha, anteriormente mi compañero tenía un único selector de fecha tanto para inicio y fin, y actualmente cambie ese único input por dos, uno para seleccionar la fecha de inicio y otro para seleccionar la fecha de fin de la búsqueda
El fallo que tengo es bastante extraño ya que modificando el script para que sea lo mas exacto posible al que utilizaba antes mi compañero junto a la llamada de ajax y el cambio en el modelo de búsqueda (Searchmodel.php) al realizar una búsqueda y filtrar entre dos fechas para obtener los resultados que se añadieron entre esas dos fechas no funciona el filtro, devolviéndome todos los archivos guardados.
Mi Código:
HTML: Se basa en un switch que al estar activo muestra los dos inputs de fecha, uno para inicio y otra para fin.
Home.php contiene el Js de los selectores
<script>
//FECHAS
$(document).ready(function() {
    var language = '<?= session("language") ?>';

    // Cargar el archivo de localización de moment.js si el idioma no es inglés
    if (language != 'en') {                
        $.getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/locale/' + language + '.js', function() {
            moment.locale(language); // Establecer el locale de moment al cargado
            initializeDatepickers(language);
        });
    } else {
        initializeDatepickers(language);
    }

    // Inicializar controles select2
    $('[data-control="select2"]').select2();
    $('[data-control="select2"]').each(function() {
        var noSearch = $(this).data('no-search') === true;
        $(this).select2({
            minimumResultsForSearch: noSearch ? Infinity : 0
        });
    });

    // Alternar la visibilidad de los campos de fecha
    $('#flexSwitchCheckedDate').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.date-field').show();
        } else {
            $('.date-field').hide();
        }
    });
});

function initializeDatepickers(language) {
    var end = moment();
    var start = moment();

    // Configuración de localización para los datepickers
    var localeData = {
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        applyLabel: "<?= lang('General.send') ?>",
        cancelLabel: "<?= lang('General.close') ?>",
        firstDay: moment.localeData()._week.dow
    };

    // Inicializar el date picker de la fecha de inicio
    $("#kt_start_date").daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        startDate: start,
        autoUpdateInput: true,
        locale: localeData
    });

    // Inicializar el date picker de la fecha de fin
    $("#kt_end_date").daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        startDate: end,
        autoUpdateInput: true,
        locale: localeData
    });

    // Manejador para aplicar el rango de fechas
    function handleDateRangeApply() {
        if ($('#flexSwitchCheckedDate').is(':checked')) {
            var startDate = $("#kt_start_date").data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var endDate = $("#kt_end_date").data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

            // Crear la variable dateRange
            var dateRange = startDate + ' - ' + endDate;

            console.log('Start Date:', startDate, 'End Date:', endDate);
            console.log('Date Range:', dateRange);

            // Enviar el rango de fechas como una sola cadena
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?= site_url('search') ?>', // URL de tu controlador
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'date_range': dateRange, // Usar la variable que has definido
                    '<?= csrf_token() ?>': '<?= csrf_hash() ?>' // Si la protección CSRF está habilitada
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    // Manejar la respuesta
                    console.log('Respuesta:', response); // Ver la respuesta en la consola
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    // Manejar el error
                    console.error('Error:', error); // Mostrar el error en la consola
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Asociar el manejador a los eventos de aplicación de los date pickers
    $("#kt_start_date").on('apply.daterangepicker', handleDateRangeApply);
    $("#kt_end_date").on('apply.daterangepicker', handleDateRangeApply);
}
</script>

SearchControler.php obtiene los datos del Js
public function result()
{
    // Codigo sin relacion...

    $userId = $this->session->userData['id'];
    $userControls = $this->session->userData['controls'];

    $data['userData'] = $this->session->userData;

    $model = new SearchModel();

    $search = $this->request->getPost('search');
    $no_search = $this->request->getPost('no_search');
    $searchType = $this->request->getPost('search_type');
    $searchTypeExact = $this->request->getPost('search_type_and');
    $status = $this->request->getPost('status');
    $tags = $this->request->getPost('tags');

    $fileType = $this->request->getPost('fileType');
    $dateRange = $this->request->getPost('date_range');
    // Aqui ya $dateRange esta vacio
    log_message('debug', 'Rango de fechas recibido en el controlador: ' . $dateRange);
    
    $selectedNodes = $this->request->getPost('selected_nodes');

    $search = $search === '' ? null : $search;
    $no_search = $no_search === '' ? null : $no_search;
    $status = $status === '' ? null : $status;
    $tags = $tags === '' ? null : $tags;
    $fileType = $fileType === '' ? null : $fileType;
    $dateRange = $dateRange === '' ? null : $dateRange;
    // Aqui ya $dateRange sigue vacio
    log_message('debug', 'Rango de fechas después de la verificación: ' . $dateRange);

    $selectedNodes = $selectedNodes === '' ? null : $selectedNodes;
    $searchTypeExact = $searchTypeExact === '' ? null : $searchTypeExact;

    $searchPerformed = true;
    $data['searchPerformed'] = $searchPerformed;

    $data['results'] = $model->search($userId, $search, $no_search, $searchType, $status, $tags, $fileType, $dateRange, $selectedNodes,  $userControls, $searchTypeExact);
    // Me muestra los 38 resultados de la busqueda sin fecha
    log_message('debug', 'Resultados de la búsqueda: ' . count($data['results']));

    // Código sin relacion...
}

SearchModel.php recibe los parametros del serachControler.php
public function search($userId, $search, $no_search, $searchType, $status, $tags, $fileType, $dateRange, $selectedNodes, $userControls, $searchTypeExact)
    {

    $builder = $this->db->table($this->table);
    
    // Más filtros de busqueda...

    // Filtro por rango de fechas
    if ($dateRange && strpos($dateRange, ' | ') !== false) {
        list($startDate, $endDate) = explode(' | ', $dateRange);

        // Registrar las fechas recibidas
        log_message('debug', 'Fecha de inicio recibida: ' . $startDate);
        log_message('debug', 'Fecha de fin recibida: ' . $endDate);

        // Convertir las fechas al formato esperado
        $startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $startDate);
        $endDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $endDate);

        // Verificar si la conversión fue exitosa
        if ($startDate && $endDate) {
            $startDate = $startDate->format('Y-m-d');
            $endDate = $endDate->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d');

            log_message('debug', 'Fecha de inicio convertida: ' . $startDate);
            log_message('debug', 'Fecha de fin convertida: ' . $endDate);

            $builder->where('date >=', $startDate);
            $builder->where('date <', $endDate);
        } else {            
            log_message('error', 'Formato de fecha no válido: ' . $dateRange);
        }
    } else {
        log_message('error', 'La fecha no llega bien o no tiene el formato esperado: ' . $dateRange);

        // Intentar dividir el rango de fechas usando el separador correcto
        if (strpos($dateRange, ' | ') !== false) {
            list($startDate, $endDate) = explode(' | ', $dateRange);

            // Registrar las fechas recibidas
            log_message('error', 'Fecha de inicio recibida (sin formato): ' . $startDate);
            log_message('error', 'Fecha de fin recibida (sin formato): ' . $endDate);

        } else {
            log_message('error', 'El formato del rango de fechas no es válido: ' . $dateRange);
        }
    }

    // Más filtros de busqueda...

    $builder->orderBy('date', 'DESC');

    if ($searchType) $query = $builder->distinct()->select('files.*,status.name as statusname, folders.tag as tagGroup')->get(50);
    else $query = $builder->distinct()->select('files.*,status.name as statusname, folders.tag as tagGroup')->get(50);


    return $query->getResultArray();
}

EDIT 24-10-2024:
Comprendiendo ya como funciona el codigo el Js envia el valor date_range a SearchController.php pero a este ya la variable llega vacia, el mal funcionamiento esta entre el envio y la recepcion de la variable
Muchísimas gracias!!

Los comentarios han sido movidos al chat; por favor, no continuar la discusión aquí. Antes de publicar un comentario bajo este, por favor revisa los propósitos de los comentarios. Los comentarios que no pidan clarificaciones o sugieran mejoras normalmente deben ser publicados como una respuesta, en [meta], o en el [chat]. Los comentarios que continúen la discusión podrán ser eliminados.

Siendo que el var_dump($this->request->getPost()) arroja esto:
["date_switch"]=> string(1) "1" 
["start_date"]=> string(10) "2024-01-10" 
["end_date"]=> string(10) "2024-05-10" 

Podemos concluir que los datos no están llegando dentro de una clave llamada date_range, sino separados, bajo las claves start_date y end_date, lo cual está bien, pues no deberías nunca mezclar las cosas, para luego seguir manipulando los datos para separar lo que debió llegar separado desde un principio.
Basta con crear los objetos DateTime, usando el formato con el que llegan, que es Y-m-d.
Entonces, si modificas el código así debería funcionar:
$startDate=$this->request->getPost('start_date');
$endDate=$this->request->getPost('end_date');

$startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $startDate);
$endDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $endDate);

if ($startDate && $endDate) {
    $endDate->modify('+1 day'); #No hay que reasignar la variable
    log_message('debug', 'Fecha de inicio convertida: ' . $startDate);
    log_message('debug', 'Fecha de fin convertida: ' . $endDate);
    $builder->where('date >=', $startDate);
    $builder->where('date <', $endDate);
} else {
    log_message('error', 'Formato de fecha no válido: ');
}

